Tesselation Combinatorics Problem
I am having trouble understanding part of the official solution to this problem:

Draw a regular hexagon. Then make a square from each edge of the hexagon. Then form equilateral triangles by drawing an edge between every pair of neighboring squares. If this figure is continued symmetrically off to infinity, what is the ratio between the number of triangles and the number of squares?


The following part makes sense: each vertex is next to 2 squares, 1 triangle, and 1 hexagon.
However, I am not following this statement: "Since the number of vertices on a square is 4, $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$ of the polygons are squares. Similarly, $\frac{1}{3}$
of the polygons are
triangles and $\frac{1}{6}$ of the polygons are hexagons, yielding $\frac{2}{3}$ as the answer."
They are dividing the number of instances of each shape per vertex by the number of vertices in each shape. I don't get why this works. Could someone please clarify why this is valid?

I suggest that you get a large piece of scratch paper, draw a fairly small hexagon in the center of the page, and then carry the geometric construction 3 levels deep.  Then, once you have visualized this, see if the official solution makes sense.

Re last comment, if you still have a question, I suggest that you embed your geometric construction as an image in the posted question, show all of your work/analysis, and then discuss your remaining confusion.  Alternatively, if you are able to, you can use software to create the image.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

"If this figure is continued symmetrically off to infinity" : I don't understand how it can be continued till infinity with squares and "equilateral triangles"

What is the source of this "official solution"? As written, things are not even well-defined and there is no attempt to prove anything in the quoted text.

The source is: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/570450471d07c094a39efaed/t/58b08c3f5016e11f95e42330/1487965247361/PUMaC2008_CombinatoricsSol.pdf

As far as I can tell, the problem is about an asymptotic count (one looks at arbitrarily large disks $B(R)$ (radius $R$) and counts the number of polygons of various kind in this disk). Then one take limits of ratios of these numbers to the total number of polygons in $B(R)$. One can make a solid math proof here by counting in a fundamental domain, appealing to amenability of $\mathbb Z^2$, etc. I am unsure, however, if you or the author of the solution know what this means. What one can say for sure is that the authors of the "official solution" have failed in their task.

Let $V$ be the number of vertices and $S$ be the number of squares. Let’s count the vertex-square incidences in two ways:

Each vertex is incident to two squares, so the number of vertex-square incidences is $2V$.
Each square is incident to four vertices, so the number of vertex-square incidences is $4S$.

But these are the same numbers, so
$$
2V = 4S\implies S = \frac{V}2.
$$
You can use the same argument for vertex-triangle and vertex-hexagon incidences.

I should add that this isn’t the best way to think about this problem because you have an infinite drawing making both $V$ and $S$ infinite. To make the ratio more precise, it’s better to identify a unit cell (because the drawing suggests it’s translation invariant, so forms a tiling of the plane) and count the number of each of those shapes in the unit cell.

Not only it is not the "best way", it is not even a valid argument.
